# widgets toolbox engine execute a python file when I choose a btn

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a question :
There is my code :

```
tb = QToolBar("Website's infos :")
tb.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
self.addToolBar(Qt.RightToolBarArea,tb2)

ip_btn = QAction(QIcon("scan.png"), "SQL MAP", self)
ip_btn.setStatusTip("Launch a scan to see website's IP")
ip_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.conn(""))
tb2.addAction(ip_btn)
```

Do you think I can execute a python file when I click on the toolbox ?

I would like to execute a scanner of website to see website ip(in python), but idk how do I execute a python file through a toolbox button

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: In the button's `clicked` signal handler you could read the file into a string and use `eval` if access to the output of the script is not required or if you need the output of the script, spawn a process running `python3 myscript.py`